# Function crashing in release mode but runs flawless in debugger

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, allocation

My program crashes on this function on the 7th line, when I call `malloc()` when I run in release mode I get the `Program.exe has stopped working message, and when I run in debugger, most of the time it succeeds but sometimes I get this message (especially on larger input):
[image: crash]

```
MONOM* polynomialsProduct(MONOM* poly1, int size1, MONOM* poly2, int size2, int* productSize)
{
    int i1, i2;
    int phSize = 1, logSize = 0;
    MONOM* product;

    product = (MONOM*)malloc(phSize*sizeof(MONOM));
    monomAllocationVerification(product);

    for (i1 = 0; i1 < size1; i1++)
    {
        for (i2 = 0; i2 < size2; i2++)
        {
            if (logSize == phSize)
            {
                phSize *= 2;
                product = (MONOM*)realloc(product,phSize*sizeof(MONOM));
                monomAllocationVerification(product);
            }

            product[logSize].coefficient = poly1[i1].coefficient * poly2[i2].coefficient;
            product[logSize].power = poly1[i1].power + poly2[i2].power;
            logSize++;
        }
    }

    mergeSort(product,logSize);
    *productSize = sumMonomsWithSamePower(product, logSize);

    return product;
}
```

---

I understand that I'm dealing with memory errors and problems, but is there any quick way to analyze my code and look for memory errors? I look at my code a dozen of times looking for this kind of errors and found nothing. (I didn't want to post the code here since its 420 lines long).

Comment: So, what is `phSize` when it crashes during debug?

Comment: When your program crashes on a malloc, especially if it is a 'sometimes' crash, the real fault is earlier in the program's execution. Is this the first call to malloc?

Comment: @meaning-matters, `phSize = 1`

Comment: @Fred, certainly not, do you suggest going over again and looking for errors around all `malloc()`s and `realloc()`s?

Comment: @Fred, what kind of bugs should I look for? I tried commenting all occurrences of `free()` which didn't help

Comment: Look for an assignment to malloc'ed space that runs past the end (buffer overflow).

Comment: A program *very* rarely crashes due to heap corruption at the code that caused the corruption, it is always discovered *later*.  So staring at this code never gets you anywhere.  Use the debug allocator to help you diagnose this, `<crtdbg.h>`

Comment: @HansPassant `crtdbg.h` is pointing on a line that is using `malloc()`, how can a memory allocation cause a leak?

Comment: It outputs `c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ex2\q2\q2.c(317) : {81} normal block at 0x002B1520, 8 bytes long.` Which is  `sum = (MONOM*)malloc(phSize*sizeof(MONOM));` how can `malloc()` cause a leak on allocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if heap corruption is detected on the first `malloc`, that means it happened earlier (not in this function or on previous pass). So the problem may lie outside this code.

However, the code also looks suspicious to me.

1. `monomAllocationVerification` has no `size` parameter, so it should work on one monom only, yet you call it only once after `realloc` on pointer to first element, despite having allocated space for quite a few monoms. Please clarify your decision.
2. It is a bit unclear why `sumMonomsWithSamePower` should return a size, and thus modify an array to store a value. May be a quirk, but still suspicious.

**UPDATE**

The problem was in other functions; a few reallocs with wrong size.

Comment: 1. `monomAllocationVerification` only verifies that the address of the pointer is not NULL, if it does the function calls `exit()`.
2. `sumMonomsWithSamePower` returns size since if you sum 2^2 and 5^2 you only need one cell of the array instead of two.

Comment: @Quaker I see, so `sumMonomsWithSamePower` actually modifies the `product` array, but never mind. Now I don't see troubles with this code, but there is still place for optimization. You perform a realloc every now and then, but in fact you *know* the amount of memory you need. It is `size1*size2*sizeof(MONOM)`. Allocate it beforehand, in the first `malloc`, so you don't have need to reallocate it. The corruption problem, however, is beyond this code. And there is no simple way to find it; but try comparing the size you expect with the size you allocated.

Comment: So you suggest I allocate the pessimist size and reallocate it if there's unused memory?

Comment: In current function - absolutely. You perform `size1*size2` iterations and increase `logSize` on every iteration, so you will always need `size1*size2*sizeof(MONOM)` memory. Note that now you allocate even more than that. But this still will not solve the problem, because it is elsewhere. Track all your allocations and loops and indexed access.

Comment: I have done that already, went through the allocations and even used `crtdbg.h` which points out which allocations cause the leaks but I can't find anywhere I'm using a memory which I haven't allocated previously.

Comment: The problem is not using a non-allocated memory. The problem is in going out of bounds of allocated memory, that causes heap corruption.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33824/discussion-between-quaker-and-lyth)

Answer (score 0):

I would check the return value of malloc() and use perror() to describe what error has occured. Also here is the documentation for [malloc()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) and [perror()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/perror.html).

```
if((product = (MONOM*)malloc(phSize*sizeof(MONOM))) == NULL)
{
      perror("ERROR: Failed to malloc ");
      return 1;
      //perror() will display a system specified string to describe the error it may tell you the error
}
```

Also do you know the size of MONOM? If not add the following line to your code.

```
printf("MONOM SIZE = %i\n", sizeof(MONOM));
```

Comment: return value is checked by `monomAllocationVerification` and the size of MONOM is 8 since it's a struct of two integers (2 times 4).